# ASP.net MVC DropLownList db.SaveChanges not saving selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

I have looked through a ton of tutorials and suggestions on how to work with DropDownList in MVC.  I was able to get most of it working, but the selected item is not saving into the database.  I am using MVC 3 and Razor for the view.

My DropDownList is getting created with the correct values and good looking HTML.  When I set a breakpoint, I can see the correct selected item ID in the model getting sent to controller.  When the view goes back to the index, the DropDownList value is not set.  The other values save just fine.

Here are the related views.  The DropDownList is displaying a list of ColorModel names as text with the ID as the value.

```
public class ItemModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ColorModel Color { get; set; }
}
public class ItemEditViewModel
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int ColorID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Colors { get; set; }
}
public class ColorModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ColorID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ItemModel> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the controller actions.

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        ItemModel itemmodel = db.Items.Find(id);
        ItemEditViewModel itemEditModel;
        itemEditModel = new ItemEditViewModel();
        itemEditModel.ItemID = itemmodel.ItemID;
        if (itemmodel.Color != null) {
            itemEditModel.ColorID = itemmodel.Color.ColorID;
        }
        itemEditModel.Description = itemmodel.Description;
        itemEditModel.Name = itemmodel.Name;
        itemEditModel.Colors = db.Colors
            .ToList()
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = x.Name,
                    Value = x.ColorID.ToString()
                });
        return View(itemEditModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(ItemEditViewModel itemEditModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ItemModel itemmodel;
            itemmodel = new ItemModel();
            itemmodel.ItemID = itemEditModel.ItemID;
            itemmodel.Color = db.Colors.Find(itemEditModel.ColorID);
            itemmodel.Description = itemEditModel.Description;
            itemmodel.Name = itemEditModel.Name;
            db.Entry(itemmodel).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(itemEditModel);
    }
```

The view has this for the DropDownList, and the others are just EditorFor().

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ColorID, Model.Colors, "Select a Color")
```

When I set the breakpoint on the `db.Color.Find(...)` line, I show this in the Locals window for itemmodel.Color:

> {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ColorModel_0EB80C07207CA5D88E1A745B3B1293D3142FE2E644A1A5202B90E5D2DAF7C2BB}

When I expand that line, I can see the ColorID that I chose from the dropdown box, but it does not save into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to set the whole `Color` object. Just set the `ColorId` property.

Change

```
itemmodel.Color = db.Colors.Find(itemEditModel.ColorID);
```

To

```
itemmodel.ColorId = itemEditModel.ColorID;
```

**Edit**

Note that your database does not store the whole object. The `Color` object in `ItemModel` is just a convenient way to access the `ColorModel` entity that is assosiated by a foreign key.

According to convention, the name of the foreign key property should be `ColorId`. Add this `int` property in your `ItemModel` class.

Comment: My ItemModel has a ColorModel property named Color, but it does not have a ColorID property.  The ColorID is inside of the Color property.  Do I need to modify my ItemModel?

Comment: I tried using `itemmodel.Color.ColorID = itemEditModel.ColorID;`, but this also did not work.

Comment: @WMIF: I am sorry I did not notice that there is nothing like `ColorId` in `ItemModel`. Yes, you need to add that. Check the edit.

Comment: Thank you @Mohayemin for the clarification.  I am familiar with the foreign key relations in databases.  I have done web dev and db work for many years, but this EF and CodeFirst thing is still new to me.  I thought that having the ColorModel accessor was part of EF building the FK.  The ColorID is getting saved into the DB now.  I just have to work on the other views to show the name of the color instead of the ID.